# How to split string in numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a lot of text in a numpy.ndarray that looks like this:

```
['This is example sentence 1.|This is example sentence 2.'
 'This is example sentence 3.'
 'This is example sentence 4.'
 'This is example sentence 5.'
 'This is example sentence 6.|This is example sentence 7.|This is example sentence 8.|This is example sentence 9.|This is example sentence 10.']
```

The array can have a large and varying number of elements and individual elements can have many sentences separated with "|".

How do I convert the example above into this:

```
 ['This is example sentence 1.'
 'This is example sentence 2.'
 'This is example sentence 3.'
 'This is example sentence 4.'
 'This is example sentence 5.'
 'This is example sentence 6.'
 'This is example sentence 7.'
 'This is example sentence 8.'
 'This is example sentence 9.'
 'This is example sentence 10.']
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a 1-dimensional array that will split elements with "|" into their own separate elements. I've tried many versions of split and can't get them to work for one reason or another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `np.char.split`:

```
# np.concatenate or np.hstack
>>> np.concatenate(np.char.split(arr.astype(str), sep='|'))

array(['This is example sentence 1.', 'This is example sentence 2.',
       'This is example sentence 3.', 'This is example sentence 4.',
       'This is example sentence 5.', 'This is example sentence 6.',
       'This is example sentence 7.', 'This is example sentence 8.',
       'This is example sentence 9.', 'This is example sentence 10.'],
      dtype='<U28')
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this: np.concatenate(np.char.split(arr, sep='|')) and got error: "string operation on non-string array"

Comment: print(arr.dtype) = "object"

Comment: How is your array created? You probably have mixed types (and what is the output of `arr.shape`?) I think your data are not clean.

Comment: Shape is `(5,)` but that will vary each time I run the code depending on how many rows of data I enter. Here's how arr was created: `arrConditions = [
    (arrTbl['Type'] == '500k'),
    (arrTbl['Type'] == 'Institution'),
]

arrChoices = [

        'text, ' + arrTbl['Party'] + '’s text|' + arrTbl['Party'] + ' text.',
        'text, ' + arrTbl['Party'] + ' text.'

arr = np.select(arrConditions, arrChoices)`

Comment: For certain arrConditions, I'm basically trying to generate more than one element in arrChoices. I couldn't figure out how to generate more than one element in the array per each condition in arrConditions. So my plan B was to add '|' between desired elements in each arrChoices and then separate into multiple elements as a second step.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have nested list inside your array? Something like `np.array(['s1', 's2', ['s3', 's4'], 's5'])`

Comment: I don't think so, with my current data, this is the pattern that the output follows: `['Text|Text'
 'Text'
 'Text|Text'
 'Text'
 'Text|Text']`

Comment: Another try: `np.concatenate(np.char.split(arr.astype(str), sep='|'))`

Comment: Thank you Corralien!!!! Your solution works perfectly!!!